# Add password to a document already signing with itext7

Tags: itext7

I'm working with **itext 7.2.2**, for now I'm facing the problem that I can't **put the password to the document after signing it digitally**, the document comes to me with a password and I have to return it with the same one after signing it, however the document that return only bears the signature.

I put an example of what I am doing in **java 8**, I am attentive to your comments.

````
```ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   InputStream pdfStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdf);
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
   WriterProperties props = new WriterProperties();

   props.setStandardEncryption(password.getBytes(), password.getBytes(), 
        EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                        EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_256 | 
  EncryptionConstants.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
  PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(baos, props);
  PdfDocument pdfDoc =new PdfDocument(reader, writer, new 
    StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
  pdfDoc.close();´´´
````

**pdf** is an array contains the document already signed

**password** is the password that will be assigned to the final document

I have noticed that if I remove new StampingProperties().useAppendMode()); so if the password is placed without embargo the signature is invalidated.

I remain attentive to your comments.

Comment: Have you tried using `new StampingProperties().useAppendMode().preserveEncryption()` yet? That being said, if you use `AppendMode`, the encryption automatically is preserved. isn't it?

Comment: Hello mkl, I just tried the option you indicate but still no success, the password is not assigned to the document and if I just put                                                 
 PdfDocument pdfDoc =new PdfDocument(reader, writer, new StampingProperties().preserveEncryption());                                                             
                                                                                                                                   then the document does put the password but the signature is invalidated.

Something that I may be missing to do?

Comment: *"pdf is an array contains the document already signed"* - I just realized that you wrote this. You cannot change passwords after a file is signed. You have to apply/keep the password when signing.

Comment: With this last comment I understand that I should do something like:        
 InputStream pdfStream_2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdf);
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfStream_2, new ReaderProperties().setPassword(pwdPdf.getBytes()));                         
            PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, byteNewPdf_2, new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());  Just like that I get the following error: Bad user password. Password is not provided or wrong password provided. Correct password should be passed to PdfReader constructor with properties.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the document is encrypted when a signatory passes but other users can continue signing it and the encryption should be maintained without invalidating any signature, is that possible?

Comment: I realized that I'm still not 100% clear about at which stages your PDF is encrypted and/or signed. Can you use a representative example PDF, run it through all the stages and share the PDF revisions at those stages for analysis?

Comment: I appreciate your support. I was making some mistakes that by reviewing the handling of the file I was able to solve.